# How to pass argument from bash to wsadmin

Tags: python, websphere, jython, was

So basically i have .sh script which includes some bash and then ./wsadmin.sh launching some .py scripts which i've made.
I need to somehow pass the argument of script from bash to .py script.

As example i have now test.sh $1:

cd /tmp/$1

./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /WAS/deploySQL.py

And inside deploySQL.py

I have some as example: AdminConfig.showAttribute(cluster, 'value')

I want to pass that $1 argument to the inside of deploySQL.py "value" field.

Sorry im a beginner could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sys.argv take a look to this example :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

so if you want to run this script you will

```
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

the result will be

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

in your case, you should run

```
./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /WAS/deploySQL.py $1
```

and replace the value variable in deploySQL.py with sys.argv[1]